# We were unable to decode the JSON response from the Mandrill API

Tags: json, api, mandrill

I am using the standard Code from: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html, `require_once 'mandrill.php';` before using it and the directory is also right. But I am getting this exception the whole time, and I dont know why

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mandrill_Error' with message 'We were
>   unable to decode the JSON response from the Mandrill API:      window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,n,t){function
>   r(t){if(!n[t]){var
>   o=n[t]={exports:{}};e[t][0].call(o.exports,function(n){var
>   o=e[t][1][n];return r(o||n)},o,o.exports)}return
>   n[t].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return
>   __nr_require;for(var o=0;op;p++)u[p].apply(s,t);return
>   s}function a(e,n){f[e]=c(e).concat(n)}function c(e){return
>   f[e]||[]}function u(){return t(n)}var
>   f={};return{on:a,emit:n,create:u,listeners:c,_events:f}}function
>   r(){return{}}var
>   o="nr@context",i=e("gos");n.exports=t()},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],ee:[function(e,n){n.exports=e("QJf3ax")},{}],3:[function(e,n)
>   in

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you get this error when the `mailservice` is down or has `Internal server errors (500)`. Embed your sending code in a `try/catch block` and use the `catch block` to fall back on another mailing service.